# Android ServerSocket Connection

Tags: android, serversocket

it might be a dumb question, but I searched and couldn't find the solution.

I have an Android App that start a ServerSocket, and my python server connect to that App and send messages, so if I have 2 apps running I'll have 2 Servers, works fine, but as the python server must connect throw IP and when the app switch to 3G or Wi-Fi, the device IP change, so, How can i solve that problem?

thanks.

Comment: why you don't use a clientsocket in android and a serversocket on python?

Comment: @rnrneverdies because the app must receive msg, not only send, as clientsocket does, the idea of the process is like GCM, but i can't use GCM

Comment: The Socket class can send and receive, to operate as client you must use the connect method, after successful connection you can use to send and receive methods to send and receive data. On the other side (Python) need to Server socket. to do this use listen method of socket or some hi level SocketServer class, on each connection  you can send and receive data. In this way the android client do pooling the Python server to receive pending messages. please see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: @rnrneverdies now I understand what you were talking about, I tried what you said and works fine for what I want.

now i want your opinion, if possible, about 2 solutions.

*The app is a serversocket, as I already told on my question, and every time the connection change I send my new IP to my server(python).

*Your suggestion, i use clientsocket to send and receive msg.
In these case, my only concern is that the server must save all connected client, and it can be thousands of clients and the client must be connected 24/7, is that a problem?